# Windows 8.1 error: The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update, visual-studio, windows-error-reporting

Hey so I have this error that keeps popping up since last windows update "The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect please see the application event log or use the command line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail", I tried looking up a solution, they all say "install Visual Studio Package" or something of that sort of thing, I would like to do that but, even when I try to install something this error keeps showing up, any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect](https://superuser.com/questions/1057460/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-the-side-by-side-configuratio) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1239995/side-by-side-configuration-error-in-windows-10)

Comment: If you want a detailed answer provide the log and the name of the application generating this error by editing your question

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur because of a WinSxS corrupted file or files.  Also, you say  *"when I try to install something this error keeps showing up"*

So then do the following:

**(1) DISM and SFC.**

Open an Admin Command Prompt and run:

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and then

SFC /SCANNOW

Allow all to finish, restart and test.

See this Microsoft Support Article

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/window-81-dism-online-cleanup-image-scanhealth/306f7335-09c3-42f6-8458-4983829dac06

**(2) Repair Install**

If the above fails, you may need to do a Repair Install with the Windows 8.1 DVD.

Insert the Windows 8.1 DVD with Windows 8.1 running.

Run Setup.exe on the DVD to run the installer. Follow directions carefully to look for the Keep settings to keep your data and apps.

Followup Note:  Windows 8.1 is near end of life. Back up your system and upgrade to Windows 10. That should also fix your issue.

Comment: This isn’t a WinSxS issue.

Comment: I saw the WinSXS issue on several threads so I just said "may be". The repairs I listed are certainly worth trying

Comment: The user doesn’t have something that is required installed.  Their Windows installation isn’t corrupt. See the duplicate candidates for more information